# how to save selected index in datagrid and set selected item back when the user reloads the page?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in a WPF project that is filled using MVVM.
When the user selects a row and then clicks the edit button a window opens.
My problem it is that, when the user comes back to DataGrid, the selected item was changed and set to first row!

I wrote this code in view model :

```
UserInfoDAL userInfoDAL;

    public UserInfoListVM()
    {

        userInfoDAL = new UserInfoDAL();
        UserInfoCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserInfo>();
        UserInfoModelCurrent = new UserInfo();

        UserInfoSelect();
    }
   private ObservableCollection<UserInfo> _UserInfoCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<UserInfo> UserInfoCollection
    {
        get { return this._UserInfoCollection; }
        set
        {
            this._UserInfoCollection = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("UserInfoCollection");
        }
    }
    private int _selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }
    public UserInfo UserInfoModelCurrent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }public void UserInfoSelect()
    {
        SelectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
        string _errorMessage = "";

        ObservableCollection<UserInfo> _UserInfoModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserInfo>();
        _UserInfoModelCollection = userInfoDAL.UserInfoSelect(null, out _errorMessage);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "خطا", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            UserInfoCollection = _UserInfoModelCollection;
        }
        Messenger.Default.Send(this, "UserInfoListNotify");


    }
```

in xaml:

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="GrdUserInfo" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding UserInfoCollection}" 
    MouseRightButtonDown="GrdUserInfo_MouseRightButtonDown" 
    LoadingRow="GrdUserInfo_LoadingRow" 
    AutoGeneratingColumn="GrdUserInfo_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding UserInfoModelCurrent,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Loaded="GrdUserInfo_Loaded" 
    SelectionChanged="GrdUserInfo_SelectionChanged" 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange‌​d}" 
    >
```

in codebehind:

```
     public UserInfoListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userInfoListViewModel = new UserInfoListVM();

        this.DataContext = userInfoListViewModel;

        Messenger.Default.Register<UserInfoListVM>(this, "UserInfoListNotify", x =>
        {
            DataGridSetting.DataGridPreparation(TabName, ref GrdUserInfo, userInfoListViewModel.UserInfoCollection, SelectedIndexRow);
        }
        );
    }
    public bool RestoreGridDefault = false;
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.Closing += window_Closing;
        window.KeyUp += Window_KeyDown;
    }

    private void GrdUserInfo_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridSetting.DataGridSetColumnPrperty(ref e);
       // e.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
    }
    private void GrdUserInfo_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridSetting.DataGridCreateContexMenu(ref GrdUserInfo, ref RestoreGridDefault, "userInfo", e);
    }
    private void GrdUserInfo_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()+1).ToString();

    }
    private void GrdUserInfo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridSetting.DataGridPreparation(TabName, ref GrdUserInfo, userInfoListViewModel.UserInfoCollection, SelectedIndexRow);
    }

    private void GrdUserInfo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        userInfoListViewModel.SelectedIndex =  GrdUserInfo.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

but its not solving my problem :(

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which lets us reproduce the issue you're having. Is that the actual XAML for your DataGrid? No event handlers, no itemssource, nothing?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No!  it is : <DataGrid x:Name="GrdUserInfo" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding UserInfoCollection}" MouseRightButtonDown="GrdUserInfo_MouseRightButtonDown"  LoadingRow="GrdUserInfo_LoadingRow"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="GrdUserInfo_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding UserInfoModelCurrent,Mode=TwoWay}"  Loaded="GrdUserInfo_Loaded"  SelectionChanged="GrdUserInfo_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >

Comment: Please put that in your question. Nobody can read that. Why did you lie about your code? Because you think you know which parts are important and which don't matter? If you knew that, you wouldn't be here asking for help.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Edited. excuse me.i don't know about this.

Comment: Thank you. Now how do you know it's not working?

Comment: @EdPlunkett i explain in above. when click a row for edit and come back selected row in data grid was changed .and i don't know why?!!

Comment: "Come back"? Do you mean that when you select a row the selection suddenly changes?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No,for example when i select Twelfth row the and click edit button , open edit window.when close edit window selected row in data grid changed to first row. please see this shot:http://s9.picofile.com/file/8292633718/Screenshot_12_.png  language in project is persian

Comment: How did you rule out the possibility that some other code is setting `SelectedIndex` back to 0? Did you put a breakpoint in the `set` block for `SelectedIndex` on your viewmodel, to find out when its being set?

Comment: @EdPlunkett no i don't use selected index 0 in project. in long rows in data grid , selected row come back to first row that It is clear .i don't know you understand my mean?? see shot : http://s8.picofile.com/file/8292634992/Screenshot_13_.png   http://s9.picofile.com/file/8292635042/Screenshot_14_.png

Comment: @EdPlunkett  Did you put a breakpoint in the set block for SelectedIndex on your viewmodel, to find out when its being set? : yes 'set' is run but no set on the data grid.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is confusing is that you say that you have a grid that "is filled with data using MVVM".

MVVM is a code-design/architecture AND the whole point of it is not to use **code-behind** but you have done it anyway.

Event handling should be done from your ViewModel and not by code-behind.

I'd suggest that you read up on MVVM do further understand how it works.

[This blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) is (In my opinion) excellent to understand MVVM-basic pattern and can hopefully help you.